# mod_rewrite 404 and rewrite is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, url-rewriting

Greetings,

I cant get my htaccess mod_rewrite working as it should..
I have some basic RewriteRules for some static underpages, a redirect from the non www-version and now I would like to add a custom 404-page (called 404.php located in my webroot.

What happens is that when I try to access the underpage it only throws the 404-message back to me over and over again... Can anyone see any problems with this code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dhb\.nu$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dhb.nu/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^policy/$ page.php?page_id=11
RewriteRule ^cookies/$ page.php?page_id=13
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Read more here: http://www.garnetchaney.com/htaccess_tips_and_tricks.shtml

Comment: SOLVED!!! Found the solutions on the problem in this text..

Incidentally, you should make your 404 page larger than 512 bytes, even when you are testing. Otherwise Internet Explorer (IE) will load what it calls its built-in "friendly HTTP error message" instead of your 404 page. The Chrome browser behaves no better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /404.php [L]
```

you should really use the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Does not make any difference.the 404-page is not displayed at all now.

Comment: Well, what is displayed then? What does show up in the apache error logs? And are you sure your RewriteBase of / is correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Actually Chrome is just saying "This link is broken" when I try to browse to a URL on my site that does not exists.